# Topology with complement included

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The convention topology definitionis: let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{T}$ be a family of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{T}$ is called a topology on $X$ if:

- Both the $\emptyset$ and $X$ are elements of $\mathcal{T}$.
- Any union of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ is an element of $\mathcal{T}$.
- Any intersection of finitely many elements of $\mathcal{T}$ is an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

My question is, if adding one extra condition:

- Every element $i$ of $\mathcal{T}$ also has it's complement $X \setminus i$ in $\mathcal{T}$.

Is there a term for topologies with this condition ?

Comment: Such collection $\tau$ is the collection of all clopen subsets of $X$ . If $(X,\tau)$ is connected then $\tau$ is trivial /indiscrete topology on $X$.

Comment: It’s not necessary connected, more of a intersection  of sigma algebra and topology